# How to allow only a single application to accept inbound network connections on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall, home-networking, windows-firewall

I am running Windows 10 Pro 1803 64 bit, and I have an application which I want to accept incoming connections on the LAN only (the computer and the other device are connected to the same internal network). On the other hand, I do not want to allow devices that are not on the LAN access to this application.

I could do this pretty quickly in Linux, but after looking through the advanced settings in the Windows 10 Firewall control panel, it seems that Windows automatically creates a whole load of rules.

I'm currently running with all incoming connections blocked even if the application is on the list of allowed applications and I just want to enable this single application, on a single port on the LAN only and I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Comment: [How to Allow Apps to Communicate Through the Windows Firewall](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/uncategorized/how-to-create-exceptions-in-windows-vista-firewall/)

Comment: Better is [Configure Windows Firewall with Advanced Security - RootUsers](https://www.rootusers.com/configure-windows-firewall-advanced-security/) - shows how to configure rules for specific apps with specified ports/protocols.